# What is the working and reactive power in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

i need help with solving this task (it's on croatian but i will translate): https://ibb.co/sb0cnsx ,it says what is the the working and reactive power for the given cirucit (Xl = 3 ohm ,Xc = 2ohm R = 2ohm, u(voltage) = 100)?

I found the equivalent resistance for the whole ciruit, 1+2j, but i don't know how to find the active and reactive power in circuit.

I think formula P = I^2 * R could help me.

in the given answers(a ,b ,c ,d ,e) 'kap' means capacitive and 'ind' means inductive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you correctly calculated the impedance then:
\$I=\dfrac{U}{Z}\$ or  simply  \$|I|=\dfrac{U}{|Z|}\$.

\$Z=\sqrt{R^2+X^2}= \sqrt{1+4}\$ then \$P=I^2\cdot R\$ and \$Q=I^2\cdot X\$

Or yet simpler:

\$P=\dfrac{U^2\cdot R}{R^2+X^2}\$ and so on

Znači D.